# Adding a suffix to all values of a column in R

Tags: r

i want to add a symbol ">" before all values of my existing column named "Fasta.headers" in R. How can I do that

Comment: please see paste0 and google

Answer (score 4):

Give a better try in searching. Answering just not to discourage you:

```
df$Fasta.headers = paste0(">",df$Fasta.headers)
```

or

```
df$Fasta.headers = paste(">",df$Fasta.headers,sep = "")
```